# Windows 10 does not detect my onboard Ethernet adapter

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

I have Windows 10 Home English on my computer. The motherboard is this: ASUS M5A97 EVO R2.0. The processor doesn't matter I guess but it's this: AMD FX-4350

Windows will not recognize my onboard Ethernet adapter, I had to install an USB Wi-Fi stick which disconnects for a few seconds every now and then. Is there any solution for making use of my onboard Ethernet adapter?

Comment: Go to https://www.asus.com/SupportOnly/M5A97_EVO_R20/HelpDesk_Download/ and download and install the driver (under LAN)

Comment: [Did you install the Realtek LAN adapter drivers?](https://www.asus.com/us/SupportOnly/M5A97%20EVO%20R2-0/HelpDesk_Download/). Your going to need to provide a great deal more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I installed the driver and it doesn't find the adapter. Also, when I looked in Devices, I could not find any "Undetected device" as it should be.